# track PDOException genereal execption when query works

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have this quite straight forward piece of code. i use AJAX and PHP to update MySQ table and the correct changes take place but i get this error every time it executes:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in /var/www/html/rollcall/classes/class.user.php:176\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/rollcall/classes/class.user.php(176): PDOStatement->fetchAll(2)\n#1 /var/www/html/rollcall/appeal-handler.php(8): USER->appealIsRead('112')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/rollcall/classes/class.user.php on line 176, referer: http://localhost/rollcall/views/notifications.php
```

now the journy starts in this JS function:

```
function removeAppeal(appeal_id){
document.getElementById('an_'+appeal_id).style.display = "none";

  jQuery.ajax({
       url: '../appeal-handler.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: { appealId: appeal_id },
       complete: function(data, status)
       {
           if(status=='success')
           {
              alert('saved!');
           }
       }
   });
};
```

and moves to this php code:

```
<?php
require_once("classes/class.user.php");

$auth_user = new USER();

$appeal_id = $_POST['appealId'];

if($auth_user->appealIsRead($appeal_id)){
  return  true;
};
?>
```

ending with the execution of this `USER` method:

```
public function appealIsRead($appeal_id){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE appeals SET `read` = 1 WHERE `appeal_id` = :appeal_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':appeal_id' => $appeal_id));
    $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}
```

is there a verification im missing here or some sort of mishandling?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `fetchall()` on an `UPDATE` query, which does **not** return any fetchable result. To use fetchall(), the query must be a `SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Make your function return $stmt instead of fetchall() result

Comment: Then you did it wrong. I *hope* you managed to remove the fetchall() call as well